# Ubuntu 14.04 won't boot after installation, only live USB boots

Tags: 14.04, boot

Basically speaking I have exactly the same problem as described in here:
[Just installed ubuntu 14.04 but after restart it wont boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493051/just-installed-ubuntu-14-04-but-after-restart-it-wont-boot)
I used a live USB to install Ubuntu and completely erase windows 10, the installation went fine but when I restarted the computer Ubuntu wouldn't boot from my HDD, instead it came up with try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu so I restarted without the live usb plugged in and I got an error...

My laptop is also Toshiba Satellite

The only difference is that I cheked my Bios and my HDD is on first position, and also i checked my partitions and my EFI Boot partition is flagged "boot".

Please help.

Comment: I tried everything and nothing works, please help... I reinstalled it couple of times and still the same problem.

Comment: and you ran boot repair? so where is the paste?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet hence, this answer:

try changing the boot priority to legacy from BIOS. It might be saying EFi or UEFI, change the option to legacy. It is also possible that your BIOS may have the option of boot priority, which might be set on EFI.

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: I have edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: Thx, but I can't find any option for priority in my bios on my Toshiba. The menu is extremely limited in fact. Only under "advanced options" I have one table that allows me to change the boot - I move up and down, so I supposed the top one is priority. And I set my HDD to the highest.

Comment: maybe these links might help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and http://askubuntu.com/questions/566120/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-boot-on-toshiba-satellite