# Ubuntu Install Toshiba Laptop Fail

Tags: boot, laptop, toshiba

I installed ubuntu 16.04 x64 on my Toshiba laptop via Bootable USB. I am booting with UEFI. Previously, only windows was installed on the laptop. I first chose 'delete disk and install ubuntu' option and when I restart, it wouldn't boot, instead I get the following error

> Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - not found

and then

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
>   or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device

And then I tried the second answer in this link [How to install Ubuntu and boot on Toshiba Satellite?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566120/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-boot-on-toshiba-satellite). Still got the same error.

> [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS

returns

> UEFI

I tried methods in this answer [Clean Install of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304144/clean-install-of-ubuntu-wont-boot-reboot-and-select-proper-boot-device) and this section [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).
After I run the Boot-Info, the pastebin link I get is:
[26107941](http://paste.ubuntu.com/26098443/)

Any help is appreciated.

SOLUTION is in my answer.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Thank you, I improved my answer. I thought the paste-bin link would give people more insight about the situation then my further explanation, as I am not very experienced and I could fail elaborating the situation.

Comment: Well done! Please try if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/507051) helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But my problem is still going on. yet I got to boot succesfully at one time, it was totally random. I could never boot again.

Comment: That sounds like a hardware issue – please carefully check especially your drive's and memory's health.

Comment: If your /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi is a copy of shimx64.efi, then you are missing the /EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi file, like the error message says.  Copy it over from /EFI/ubuntu.grubx64.efi.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you for your reply.  I have booted from the USB now.
My folder /media/ubuntu/a58fea47-5214-4a17-b847-b0d873065c1d/boot  is empty. 
systemd-bootx64.efi is located at /media/ubuntu/a58fea47-5214-4a17-b847-b0d873065c1d/usr/lib/systemd/boot/efi, 
grubx64.efi.signed is located at /media/ubuntu/a58fea47-5214-4a17-b847-b0d873065c1d/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed, 
shimx64.efi is located at /media/ubuntu/a58fea47-5214-4a17-b847-b0d873065c1d/usr/lib/shim
Can you please clarify which file from which location to copy and paste? I couldnt figure out which one is supposed to be EFI/Boot

Comment: Use /usr/lib/shim/simx64.efi.signed to copy to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signe‌​d/grubx64.efi.signed copied to /EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi.  Of course, these files (not renamed) should also be in /EFI/ubuntu if the install completed.  The Toshiba will fall back to the /EFI/Boot versions if the first entry in boot order fails, before the second one is tried.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I added the solution steps.

Comment: If you solve your own problem, please place the solution as an answer and accept that answer.  Adding "[SOLVED]" to your question title is not how questions are marked solved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I first mounted sda1, the EFI partition. You can check yours with

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

   and mount it with

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
2. Within this mounted `sda` partition, I copied `grubx64.efi` and `shimx64.efi` from `/EFI/ubuntu` to `/EFI/Boot`.